# Is there any negative effect for using cropped images with the TFRecord format?

Tags: tensorflow

The TensorFlow Object Detection API requires TFRecord image cropping properties, like so:

```
{
  'image/height': 1800,
  'image/width': 2400,
  'image/filename': 'image1.jpg',
  'image/source_id': 'image1.jpg',
  'image/encoded': ACTUAL_ENCODED_IMAGE_DATA_AS_BYTES,
  'image/format': 'jpeg',
  'image/object/bbox/xmin': [0.7255949630314233, 0.8845598428835489],
  'image/object/bbox/xmax': [0.9695875693160814, 1.0000000000000000],
  'image/object/bbox/ymin': [0.5820120073891626, 0.1829972290640394],
  'image/object/bbox/ymax': [1.0000000000000000, 0.9662484605911330],
  'image/object/class/text': (['Cat', 'Dog']),
  'image/object/class/label': ([1, 2])
}
```

But I have a data-set of pre-cropped images (as in each image only shows the object to be classified). Would there be any downside in the training process of providing pre-cropped image data with xmin ymin of 0 and xmax ymax of the cropped image size? My main concern is of whether or not the training system might otherwise use contextual data nearby the cropped selections.

My question would probably be better phrased as "Do TensorFlow models potentially use contextual details nearby locations selected in TFRecord files for training?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you definitely need the bounding box information to train an object detector. Do they potentially use contextual information? Maybe, but it's a learned behaviour.

You need to provide images where your objects are visible in multiple backgrounds, scales, illuminations, etc in order to train a network to robustly detect an object.
If you only have pre-cropped images all you can train is an image classifier, the detection part won't learn anything useful from those images.

Comment: I know I need the bounding box information. I'm asking if the image referenced by the bounding box needs to be any larger than the bounding box. I'm not sure you fully understood my question. I built a tool where I can walk through frames of a video, select rectangles containing just the object to classify, and export them as individual jpegs and creates an XML file alongside the image of that selection, like shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&t=1618s note the timestamp). The difference is that example exports the full image with the cropped XML coords, where as (1/2)

Comment: I understand your question, but you don't get my point: you need to train the detector to find the object. All your samples have a bounding box that is (once normalized to the image width/height) the vector [0,01,1], because the whole image is "the" object for all your samples. The network won't learn to find the object in a bigger frame, but rather it will learn that the "correct" answer for "where's the object?" is [0,0,1,1] because it's always that.

Comment: (2/2) my program exports the cropped piece of the image and the XML coords are basically xmin, ymin 0, xmax, ymax image width / height. Afterwards, this script converts the xml, image data to tfrecords: https://github.com/nicknochnack/GenerateTFRecord/blob/main/generate_tfrecord.py

My question isn't whether or not I need a diversified set of images (multiple backgrounds, scales, etc), but whether the image samples in a TFRecord can be standalone images.

Comment: Oh, ok I think I understand you now. You're saying the training process works by using the full image to identify the object and test fitness. I see. I thought the developer later provided training images for the model to test against. Good to know.